# Select elements within certain range per column in a 2D NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have a `2D` `NumPy` array containing elements like this:

```
[[-10,  0]
 [-9,   1]
 [ 9,  -5]
 [-8,   6]
 [-7,  -5]
 [-7,  -6]
 [ 0, -10]]
```

I want to store *only* those elements whose:

1. the first column's value is in the range: `-10 <= x <= 0`

**and**

2. the second column's value is in the range: `-9 <= y <= 1`

The array after selection should look as follows:

```
[[-10,  0]
 [-9,   1]     
 [-7,  -6]
 [-7,  -5]]
```

Comment: Look into `np.logical_and()`.

Comment: @Divakar how do i use it for 2d arrays? Is there a way in which i dont have to split the 2d array into 2 arrays and then apply `logical_and()` ?

Comment: You don't need to split, just slice : `a[:,0]` and `a[:,1]`.

Comment: @Divakar Limits wont be same for x and y, i just put same for the sake this example. I'll edit it in the question.

Comment: Use `(a[:,0]>=-10) & (a[:,0]<=0)` for col0, similarly for col1 with corresponding limits and then do `AND` of those two masks and use boolean indexing to select rows off `a` with a[mask].

Comment: @Divakar Could you post this as an answer? I'd like to accept your answer as this is the faster method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
In [78]: a   # Input array
Out[78]: 
array([[-10,   0],
       [ -9,   1],
       [  9,  -5],
       [ -8,   6],
       [ -7,  -5],
       [ -7,  -6],
       [  0, -10]])

In [79]: col0m = (a[:,0]>=-10) & (a[:,0]<=0) # Column-0 mask

In [80]: col1m = (a[:,1]>=-9) & (a[:,1]<=1) # Column-1 mask

In [81]: a[col0m & col1m] # AND of masks and then index into input array
Out[81]: 
array([[-10,   0],
       [ -9,   1],
       [ -7,  -5],
       [ -7,  -6]])
```

Another approach -

```
In [99]: a    # Input array
Out[99]: 
array([[-10,   0],
       [ -9,   1],
       [  9,  -5],
       [ -8,   6],
       [ -7,  -5],
       [ -7,  -6],
       [  0, -10]])

In [100]: a[((a >= [-10, -9]) & (a <=[0, 1])).all(1)]
Out[100]: 
array([[-10,   0],
       [ -9,   1],
       [ -7,  -5],
       [ -7,  -6]])
```

Comment: This is even better than the previously proposed method! **Avg Execution time with array size = 600 elements**: `previous approach =  0.000411225449045` `current approach  =  0.000109511125017`. Great answer! Thanks :D

Comment: The vectorized approach is slightly better than the 2nd one. Second one's avg execution time is around `0.000142266684732`. Man you really know your stuff hunh?! :D

Comment: @hulkinBrain You mean the second approach `a[((a >= [-10, -9]) & (a <=[0, 1])).all(1)]` is better than the first one, right?

Comment: No, the vectorized one is better than `a[((a >= [-10, -9]) & (a <=[0, 1])).all(1)]`. Tried both approaches with **array size = 1200**, vectorized trumps the 2nd method by a considerable  amount margin. `vectorized method: 0.000202400025702` `2nd approach: 0.000357377823159`

Comment: @hulkinBrain Ah yes, the first one is memory efficient as it creates 1D mask instead of 2D mask as with the second approach and hence the benefits with the first. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

A simple iterative approach to do this would be:

```
data = [[-10,  0],
 [-9,   1],
 [ 9,  -5],
 [-8,   6],
 [-7,  -5],
 [-7,  -6],
 [ 0, -10]]

final = []
for outer_values in data:
    if -10 <= outer_values[0] <= 0 and  -9 <= outer_values[1] <= 1:
        final.append(outer_values)
```

output:

```
[[-10, 0], [-9, 1], [-7, -5], [-7, -6]]
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect! But i have to give the edge to @Divakar. That method executes slightly faster than this one. My calculations are to be done on cloud in real time so time is of the essence. Take my upvote :D Thanks mate! Execution time for this is: `0.000515149271765s` and his method is: `0.000367504808572`

Comment: Yeah no problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be using list comprehension:

```
 data = [[-10,  0],
 [-9,   1],
 [ 9,  -5],
 [-8,   6],
 [-7,  -5],
 [-7,  -6],
 [ 0, -10]]

[x for x in data if -10 <= x[0] <= 0 and -9 <= x[1] <=1]
```

Comment: Yes this is good too! But its average execution time is: `0.000490425459102s`. Still Divakar's method is faster. Take my upvote though! Thanks :D